# Can these sentences be used to mean you are busy?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I'm stuck with some things

> I'm tied up with something

Both are literal translations from my native language. I think the first one works but second one doesn't. Are there any more natural phases to convey the same that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Yes to the first. "I'm tied **up** with something" for the second

Comment: @gotube My bad. I forgot to ad "up". Can you please post your comment in the answer tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both phrases are correct and natural ways to say you're busy.

Here are some other common phrases that mean "I'm busy", and in parentheses (preposition ____) the thing I'm busy with:

> I've got a lot on my plate.
> I'm swamped (with progress reports).
> I'm up to my eyeballs (in customer complaints).